# Работа с прокси Titanium.web.proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

Как можно остановить get запрос на открытие веб-сайта, если этот сайт находится в моем black списке веб-сайтов? Используя прокси Titanium.web.proxy.

---

Вот фрагмент кода прокси:

```csharp
static string host = Dns.GetHostName();
static string ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[0].ToString();
static ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer();
public void Start_sniffing()
{
    proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
    ExplicitProxyEndPoint explicitEndPoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 8000, true)
    {

    };
    proxyServer.AddEndPoint(explicitEndPoint);
    proxyServer.Start();

    foreach (var endPoint in proxyServer.ProxyEndPoints)
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on '{0}' endpoint at Ip {1} and port: {2} ",
        endPoint.GetType().Name, endPoint.IpAddress, endPoint.Port);

    proxyServer.SetAsSystemHttpProxy(explicitEndPoint);

    Console.Read();
}
static private async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WebSession.Request.Method == "GET")
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(e.WebSession.Request.Url);
        Console.WriteLine(e.WebSession.Request.RequestUri.Host);
        foreach (Class2 c3 in blackList)
        {
            if (e.WebSession.Request.RequestUri.Host == c3.name)
            {
                switch (c3.status_id)
                {
                    case 1: MessageBox.Show("Сайт {0} не безопасен и Заблокирован!!!", c3.name);break;
                    case 2: MessageBox.Show("Сайт {0} Не рекомендуется!!!", c3.name);break;
                }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Так вот если срабатывает OnRequest(), то происходит проверка, и если запрос Get, то мы ищем веб-ссылку в списке, и если находим, выводим сообщение. Но вот как остановить загрузку веб-страницы, вопрос?

Comment: просто не делать запрос, проверять на присутствие в чёрном списке до запроса.

Comment: @DigitalCore Но ведь проверка будет начинаться только в том случае если будет реализован вход.И узнать о том какой сайт надо искать в black списке можно только после запроса

Comment: вы хоть сами понимаете о чем пишете ? я например нет ! Приведите пример кода, и опишите его, для того чтоб понимать откуда вообще берутся урл, или гет вы в воздух отправляете ?

Comment: @DigitalCore Выложил кусок кода